# Lotus Notes how to getsession in Java Script Library

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have create a Script Library in Java Language, not Java Agent. 
In Java Agent, I can use

```
Session s = getSession()
```

to get current session 
I use the following code to call Java in Script Library

```
Dim mySession  As JavaSession
Dim myClass As JavaClass
Dim myObject As JavaObject

Set mySession = New JavaSession()
Set myClass = mySession.GetClass("JFrameTest")
Set myObject = myClass.CreateObject()
```

Since I do not know user's password and I don't want user to enter password
So, I can't use the following code

```
 notessession = NotesFactory.createSession("","",password)
```

Is is possible to getsession directly In Java Script Library?

Comment: Have you tried `notessession = NotesFactory.createSession();`?

Comment: Yes. I got this error.  NotesException: Cannot create a session from an agent
 at lotus.domino.local.Session.checkJavaConnect(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.local.Session.createSessionWithFullAccess(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess(Unknown Source)
 at JFrameTest.main(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found this post [LS2J bridge and Notes Session](https://turumbay.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/ls2j-bridge-and-notes-session/) in Russian. 
I solved my problem. According to my understanding, **this is an architectural limitation**, but the author gave solution. Thanks to him.